# Making a bash script to update/download github tools

Tags: bash

I can't get the following script to work like this:
There is a file named githubrepos.txt with urls for example "https://github.com/GDSSecurity/Windows-Exploit-Suggester". The scripts checks if the folder already exists in /opt/ last part of the given url.

The script breaks on the part where it should check if the folder even exists. It always goes to the else part even if it exists. I think it hase something to do with the if [ -d $localdir ] part. Probably with the $localdir variable. I spend hours on it and cant get it to be fixed. Would like some help, its my first script written.

```
#!/bin/bash    
#Start downloading github repos
for repos in $(cat githubrepos.txt)
do
  localrepodir="/opt/${repos##*/}"
  echo $localrepodir
  if [ -d $localrepodir ];
    then
    echo ${repos##*/}
    echo "Already exists, updating tool with git pull";
    cd $(echo $localrepodir | tr -d '\r');
    git pull
    else
    echo ${repos##*/}
    echo "Tool needs to be cloned";
    git clone $repos
  fi
done
```

Comment: I tested with an abbreviated form of your script, and the `if .. else` logic worked fine;  are you saying that for a given entry in `githubrepos.txt`, the above script outputs *both* `... updating it with git pull` *and* `cloning $repos` ?

Comment: There are several common problems with the code in the question.  See the "Before asking about problematic code" section of the [Stack Overflow 'bash' tag Info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).  Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I would replace `localrepodir=/opt/$(echo $repos | awk -F "/" '{print $5}')` with `localrepodir="/opt/${repos##*/}"` See also [Manipulating Strings](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html). Setting `IFS=$'\n'` is also not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. @JGK I edited it.

Comment: @landru27 i edited my post with a better explenation. and included some of the tips given.

Comment: `[ -d $anything ]` is indeed broken, but then, so is  `for item in $(cat file)`. The former needs to be `[ -d "$anything" ]` (the quotes are essential!); for the latter, see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: In general, you shouldn't trust `echo $foo` to be useful/meaningful/correct either. Use `set -x` to enable debug logging, and **always** quote your expansions (that means `echo "$foo"`, not `echo $foo`, as described in [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo))

Comment: ...beyond the above, I still don't see this meeting MCVE requirements -- a good MCVE includes everything someone else needs to reproduce the problem themselves *as part of the question itself* (and is actually tested to reproduce the issue when copied-and-pasted). Surely you don't expect us to create a bunch of directories in `/opt` to  be able to test our answers.

Comment: Found a ^m in all of the links after i did cat -v <<< "$localrepodir". Need to put tr -d '\r' after the variable. When i do that like: <code>  localrepodir=(/opt/${repos##*/} | tr -d 'r' </code> and then echo the variable. I just get a blank line

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks I edited the variables with doubble colons.It only creates one if you pick a github repositorie and put it in the textfile. Dont know what else can reproduce the problem without making an directory. If i just check if opt exists it does. It really has to do with getting the folder name out of the url and the ^m thingy when i do the cat. Can you look at the comment above. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: The "`^m` thingy" is the very first item in the "Before asking about problematic code" list at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info. In this case, it's your `githubrepos.txt` that has literal carriage returns in it (before the newlines). You may have a directory named `/opt/foo`, but you *don't* have a directory named `/opt/foo$'\r'`, which is what it's looking for if your input file is a DOS text file.

Comment: The instructions telling you to do `tr -d '\r'` meant for it to be in a context where it'll modify the contents of your file as they're read; so, say, `while IFS= read -r repos; do ...; done < <(tr -d '\r' <githubrepos.txt)`. You don't want to call `tr` a separate time for every line -- that's wildly inefficient compared to just trimming the value in-place inside the loop body (which you could do with, for example, `repos=${repos%$'\r'}`).

Comment: `[ -d $localrepodir ]`, after all, isn't using the value you put through `tr`, so it doesn't gain any benefit from the narrow (and extremely inefficient -- `$(echo anything | tr ...)` is expensive to run) fix already present.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general answer to the sorts of issues you are facing.  My hope is that it helps you with your specific case.

The advice from @Charles Duffy is on target; there are many bash pitfalls that are easy for beginners to fall into, but also easy to avoid, e.g., by reading the advice in the articles linked.  You state quite clearly that you are a beginner, and you seem very willing to learn, so I highly recommend you read the links @Charles Duffy provided, and follow the advice.

For starters, **switch to using a `while read LINE; do ... done < FILE` structure** for your input loop.  It is far superior to `for LINE in $(COMMAND)`.  I have 25+ years of falling into all of the bash pitfalls to back me up on this.

Secondly, **reduce your problem**.  Take out the `git` commands and take out the directory operations, like `cd` and the `-d` test.  Your problem is not with those things, it's with your input.  You need a script that shows you *exactly* what is going on with your input.  Not only will that be much closer to the MCVE that is the basis of a SO question, it is likely to help you solve the problem on your own.  Here's an example:

```
#!/bin/bash    

while read LINEIN
do
  echo "XXX ${LINEIN} OOO"
done < inputfile
```

Note that this would have revealed your carriage-return problem right away.  e.g., I made an input file using these commands:

```
echo 'one'                     > inputfile
echo 'two two'                >> inputfile
echo -e 'three three three\r' >> inputfile 
echo 'four four four four'    >> inputfile
```

and with the above script it yields:

```
XXX one OOO
XXX two two OOO
 OOOthree three three
XXX four four four four OOO
```

That shows the carriage-return quite clearly.  Thus, I can modify by script:

```
while read LINEIN
do
  LINETRIM=`echo "$LINEIN" | tr -d '\r'`
  echo "XXX ${LINETRIM} OOO"
done < inputfile
```

and get:

```
XXX one OOO
XXX two two OOO
XXX three three three OOO
XXX four four four four OOO
```

A minimal working script like this can also be the basis for whatever utility you are writing, as you incrementally add in logic, testing each change along the way, until you arrive back at a script looking for directories and issuing `git` commands.

Again, this is general advice for writing `bash` scripts and for reducing a problem to its essentials, for more precise troubleshooting.  And again, this is just the beginning.  Read the [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) guides for starters, and my favorite `bash` reference [Bash Guide for Beginners](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/).

HTH.

Comment: I'd suggest `while read -r linein; do linein=${linein%$'\r'}` inside your loop, insofar as the OP's issue is narrowly/immediately caused by trailing carriage returns (which they're only stripping for a subset of their operation). Note the use of lower-case names for application-defined variables, as called for by POSIX convention as documented at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html -- the built-in [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) approach being much more efficient than `tr`.

Comment: (BTW, personally, I *wouldn't* have answered this one at this point -- note the bullet point regarding questions which "have already been asked and answered many times before" in the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer; the knowledgebase is better served by narrow questions that can have well-targeted answers than with lots of entries receiving the same general advice, however solid/useful/well-written that advice may be -- a better place for general advice is [the tag wiki info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info))

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : re: stripping newlines, agreed, and up-voted;  that does seem like a better way to do it;  re: POSIX lower-case variable names, I can also agree with that; old habits die hard ;-)

Comment: Thanks i'm going to tried it out and start over from what you wrote and play with it so I understand what it does.

Comment: @landru27 and charles Duffy. Thanks for the help i got the script working. Need to dive deeper into the material you guys gave me to fully understand it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JonySchats : I'm glad it worked out;  if my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the solution, or at least up-voting it  (or both!);  the SO rep really helps;  thx!